# Swift generics - strategies for handling ARC type modifiers?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift, generics

I am trying to write a simple property observer that can be used to see updates to a type - ie a public form of didSet.  The basic implementation was easy enough, but I then wanted to use it for both strong (value and reference) types and weak (reference) types.  The motivation for the latter was to serve as a lazy caching strategy wherein a shared resource would remain in use until the last observer freed it, whereupon it would query for the value again - generally from NSURLCache, but otherwise a remote server.  In short, I wanted a transparent multi-tiered cache.

I have done things like this in C++, where I had stored either a type, or a type wrapped in smart pointer, through the use of a trait with typedef's for Type, StoredType, etc, so I could pass a trait for value types, or a trait for ref-counted pointer types etc.

From my understanding of Swift though, the unowned and weak modifiers are applied to the property and not to the type per se, so you can't for example do something like:

> typealias StorageType = weak T

To work around this limitation, I abstracted my generic type T to always use a storage container, where the container could use either the direct type, or a weak reference to what would have to be a class-based `AnyClass` type.  (This effort itself was cludged by the fact that you can't override assignment operators and that conversion functions were abandoned in the early betas)

Frustratingly, I ran into compiler bugs where it just segfaulted.

Given that I can't be the first person to have tried to solve this type of problem, has anybody found a clean way through it?  Obviously the segfault is just another compiler bug, but perhaps there is a simpler solution?

For reference, my code (with the segfault inducing code in comments) is:

```
public class ObserverSubscription : Hashable {

    // public (hashable)
    public var hashValue: Int { return token }

    // private
    private init(token:Int, observable:ObservableProtocol) {
        self.token = token
        self.observable = observable
    }

    deinit {
        self.observable.unsubscribe(self)
    }

    private var token:Int
    private var observable:ObservableProtocol
}


public func ==(lhs: ObserverSubscription, rhs: ObserverSubscription) -> Bool {
    return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
}



public protocol Storage {
    typealias T
    typealias StorageType
    init(t:StorageType)
    var element:StorageType { get set }
}

public class Weak<Type:AnyObject> : Storage {
    typealias T = Type
    typealias StorageType = T?
    public required init(t:StorageType) { element = t }
    public weak var element:StorageType
}


public class Strong<Type> : Storage{
    typealias T = Type
    typealias StorageType = T
    public required init(t:StorageType) { element = t }
    public var element:StorageType
}


public protocol ObservableProtocol {
    func unsubscribe(subscription:ObserverSubscription)
}


public class Observable<T, Container:Storage where T == Container.T> : ObservableProtocol {

    public typealias StorageType = Container.StorageType
    public typealias Subscription = ObserverSubscription
    public typealias ChangeNotifier = (Container.StorageType) -> ()


    public init(_ t:Container.StorageType) {
        self.value = Container(t:t)
    }

    public init(_ source:Observable<T, Container>) {
        self.value = Container(t:source.value.element)
    }


    public func subscribe(notifier:ChangeNotifier) {
        let subscription = Subscription(token: token++, observable: self)
        subscriptions[subscription] = notifier
    }

    public func unsubscribe(subscription:Subscription) {
        subscriptions.removeValueForKey(subscription)
    }

    public func subscription(notifier:(Container.StorageType) -> ()) -> Subscription {
        let subscription = Subscription(token: token++, observable: self)
        subscriptions[subscription] = notifier
        return subscription
    }

    public func update(t:Container.StorageType) {
        self.value.element = t
    }

    public private(set) var value:Container { didSet {
        for n in subscriptions.keys {
            self.subscriptions[n]!(self.value.element)
        }}}


    private var token:Int = 0
    private var subscriptions: [Subscription: ChangeNotifier] = [:]
}


public class ValueObserver<T> : Observable<T, Strong<T>> {
    override init(_ t:StorageType) {
        super.init(t)
    }
}

// dare ye segfault?

//public class WeakObserver<T:AnyObject> : Observable<T, Weak<T>> {
//    override init(_ t:StorageType) {
//        super.init(t)
//    }
//}
```

My actual code was a little more involved, I derived a lazily loading class from the observer, but this too, induced a segfault:

```
//public class LazyLoader<T:AnyObject> : Observable<T, Weak<T>> {
//
//    override init(_ t:StorageType) {
//        super.init(t)
//    }
//
//    // do lazy loading here
//}
```

I have tested the observer in isolation, outside of the missing-trait work around, but has been many characters since I tested it.  My goal at this point is to find a solution that compiles (and which could hopefully be simpler)

Thanks!

Comment: Unless your objects and properties shall not be NSObjects, you may take a look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-XID_8

Comment: Yeah, it is for swift, and I wanted something pretty lightweight and easy (closures)